# tkinter - Stop PanedWndow resize

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've been using the following code from the effbot tutorial as a base:

```
from Tkinter import *

m1 = PanedWindow()
m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

left = Label(m1, text="left pane")
m1.add(left)

m2 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL)
m1.add(m2)

top = Label(m2, text="top pane")
m2.add(top)

bottom = Label(m2, text="bottom pane")
m2.add(bottom)

mainloop()
```

My issue is that I have two widgets in m2; a graph and a datatable. On a certain operation, the graph pushes the datatable up so it can't be seen. Is it possible to stop the internal panel elements disrupting each others size?

I'd still like to be able to resize manually though if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum size that you would like a window to go with the `minsize` argument:

```
m1 = PanedWindow()
m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

left = Label(m1, text="left pane")
m1.add(left)
m1.paneconfig(left, minsize=200)
```

See more options here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/panedwindow.htm#Tkinter.PanedWindow.paneconfigure-method

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried that now, but it unfortunately doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: My main concern is that this is incompatible with ttk widgets

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to add to the answer of @Novel, but if you use `, minsize =` when using `.add()` you can make it so it doesn't get under a certain size.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

m1 = PanedWindow()
m1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

left = Label(m1, text="left pane")
m1.add(left)

m2 = PanedWindow(m1, orient=VERTICAL)
m1.add(m2, minsize=50)

top = Label(m2, text="top pane")
m2.add(top,minsize=50)

bottom = Label(m2, text="bottom pane")
m2.add(bottom,minsize=)

mainloop()
```

This only works when changing the dimensions of the panels. If you change the size of the window so that is smaller than the min size of the panels, they will get smaller than what you want so you may have to set a min size for the window.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by putting both the canvas and the Pandastable in a frame and setting the height manually.

It seems that when Pandastable is updating itself it sets it's height to 0, which then has the effect of allowing the canvas to expand to fit the space.

I'm not sure of the technicalities behind it, but it works!